Change ngx-datatable checkbox color to use my custom bootstrap primary variable
I am using angular 17, bootstrap 5 and swimlane's ngx-datatable.
The ngx-datatable checkbox is defaulting to bootstrap original primary color. I cannot see where to override this color with a class or force the use of my variable overrides.
I am not using material. Only basic .bootstrap class
I have tried :ng-deep, ng-template and cellClass:
::ng-deep .ngx-datatable .datatable-body-cell .datatable-checkbox .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background-color: var(--bs-primary) !important; 
    border-color: var(--bs-primary) !important;
}

::ng-deep .ngx-datatable .datatable-body-cell .datatable-checkbox .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
border-color: var(--bs-border) !important; 
}

.aba-checkbox {
    .datatable-checkbox {
        input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
            background: var(--bs-primary) !important;
            background-color: var(--bs-primary) !important;
        }
    }
}

Please help
